# Using flatten in pytorch v1.0 Sequential module

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Due to my CUDA version being 8, I am using torch 1.0.0

I need to use the Flatten layer for Sequential model. Here's my code :

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
print(torch.__version__)
# 1.0.0
from collections import OrderedDict

layers = OrderedDict()
layers['conv1'] = nn.Conv2d(1, 5, 3)
layers['relu1'] = nn.ReLU()
layers['conv2'] = nn.Conv2d(5, 1, 3)
layers['relu2'] = nn.ReLU()
layers['flatten'] = nn.Flatten()
layers['linear1'] = nn.Linear(3600, 1)
model = nn.Sequential(
layers
).cuda()
```

It gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-38-080f7c5f5037> in <module>
      6 layers['conv2'] = nn.Conv2d(5, 1, 3)
      7 layers['relu2'] = nn.ReLU()
----> 8 layers['flatten'] = nn.Flatten()
      9 layers['linear1'] = nn.Linear(3600, 1)
     10 model = nn.Sequential(

AttributeError: module 'torch.nn' has no attribute 'Flatten'
```

How can I flatten my conv layer output in pytorch 1.0.0?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just make a new Flatten layer.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class Flatten(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        return input.view(input.size(0), -1)

layers = OrderedDict()
layers['conv1'] = nn.Conv2d(1, 5, 3)
layers['relu1'] = nn.ReLU()
layers['conv2'] = nn.Conv2d(5, 1, 3)
layers['relu2'] = nn.ReLU()
layers['flatten'] = Flatten()
layers['linear1'] = nn.Linear(3600, 1)
model = nn.Sequential(
layers
).cuda()
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [source](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.0.0/tensors.html): `flatten` method is available in the `torch.tensor` package in version 1.0.0.

You tried to import `flatten` method using `torch.nn` package therefore you got an attribute error.

For example:

```py
from torch.nn import Module
from torch.tensor import Tensor

class Net(Module):
    def __init__():
        .
        .
    
    def forward(self, x):
        .
        .
        x = Tensor.flatten(x, 1)
        .
        .
        return x
```